# " Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined" error

Tags: angular, systemjs

I try to use SystemJS to load modules that were previously compiled into ES5. I have the following error but I don't know how to interpret the error message:

```
Error: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined(…)
  Promise.reject (async)
  g @ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597
  y @ system.src.js:4597
  w @ system.src.js:4597
  p @ system.src.js:4597
  h @ system.src.js:4597
  (anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4597
```

Here is the configuration within my HTML file:

```
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/systemjs/systemjs/0.19.6/dist/system.js"></script>
(...)
<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {        
      somepackage: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      src: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
  System.import('src/somefile')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Is there some debug mode / traces I can enable?

I try to use the source of Angular2 directly instead of the bundled JS files.

Thanks very much for your help!
Thierry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that is folder **node_modules** publicly accessible!

If it is so, you can use this SystemJS config file:

```
System.config({
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    map: {
        "app": './src',
        "angular2": 'node_modules/angular2',
        'rxjs/operator/*' : 'node_modules/rxjs/add/operator/*',
        "rxjs": 'node_modules/rxjs',
        "reflect-metadata": 'node_modules/reflect-metadata/temp/Reflect.js',
        "zone.js": 'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js'
    },
    packages: {
        app: {
            defaultExtension: 'js',
            format: 'register'
        },
        angular2: {
            defaultExtension: 'js',
        },
        rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'reflect-metadata': {
            format: 'global'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Vlado! This was very useful ;-) This almost made me crazy! I did a minor update to use `angular2-polyfills.js` instead of `reflect-metadata` and `zone.js` directly...

Comment: I planned to write a blog post on this because it can be useful to link apps on Angular2 TypeScript sources for debugging purposes...

Comment: Yes, that would be cool. This setup is good for custom bundling, it gives you more control.... I assume that we don't need everything that is inside angular.js, http.js...

Comment: Definitely agreed! My ultimate goal was here to be able to debug / execute step by step the Angular2 TypeScript souce code ;-) You're SystemJS is cool since it allows to provide a fine selection of what / how to load...