# Ruler service not working as local dependency

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I based my code using this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/81nWDyreYMzkunihfRgX?p=preview

As you can see is loading dependencies remotely (scripts with http/s), then I change them using node and replacing all dependencies locally with a package.json and tsconfig.json.

However, when changing the ruler and rectangle dependencies to local like this:

```
import {Ruler, Rectangle} from "angular2/src/platform/browser/ruler";
```

Appears an error saying:

```
"SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
Evaluating http://localhost:3000/angular2/src/platform/browser/ruler
Error loading http://localhost:3000/src/main.ts" angular2-polyfills.js:138:14

SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8452#issuecomment-220460761

> mhevery commented 12 days ago
>   We have decided to remove Ruler service, and so it is not part of the public API.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add this line in your SystemJS configuration:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

(...)

<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    },
    map: {
      'angular2/src/platform/browser/ruler': 'node_modules/angular2/src/platform/browser/ruler.js'
    }
  });
  System.import('app/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

You have then the corresponding object when using the import:

```
import {Ruler} from 'angular2/src/platform/browser/ruler';
console.log(Ruler);
// print: Ruler(domAdapter) {
//    this.domAdapter = domAdapter;
// }
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are importing Angular2 from bundles:

```
angular2.min.js or ( angular.js | angular.dev.js )
```

I you check file: `./node_modules/angular2/bundles/overview.md` you will see that angular2 is consisted of:

- angular2/core
- angular2/common
- angular2/compiler
- angular2/platform/browser
- angular2/platform/common_dom
- angular2/instrumentation

no **src/** folder!

If you want to to import `angular2/src/platform/browser/ruler` in your app, you must serve `node_modules/angular2` folder to your app, **no bundles this time**!

If you are using SystemJS, consider this config:

```
System.config({
        defaultJSExtensions: true,
        map: {
            "app": './src',
            "angular2": 'node_modules/angular2',
            'rxjs/operator/*' : 'node_modules/rxjs/add/operator/*',
            "rxjs": 'node_modules/rxjs',
            "reflect-metadata": 'node_modules/reflect-metadata/temp/Reflect.js',
            "zone.js": 'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js'
        },
        packages: {
            app: {
                defaultExtension: 'js',
                format: 'register'
            },
            angular2: {
                defaultExtension: 'js',
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'reflect-metadata': {
                format: 'global'
            }
        }
    });
```

**node_modules** folder is publicly accessible!

Comment: Thanks very much, @Vlado! Your configuration allows me to fix this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34860077/cannot-read-property-resolve-of-undefined-error ;-) If you want to answer this question, I'll accept your answer...

Comment: it will be my honor to help you :)