# Delegate event bind angular 2

Tags: angular

Is there a way to bind an event to the body, and delegate to a choosen element? For example:

```
<div (body.mousemove)='foo()'>Move over me.</div>
```

I need this for a range slider I am creating, the user should be able to move the slider even when their mouse is not inside the element, so I need to bind the actual event to the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<div (body:mousemove)='foo()'>Move over me.</div>
```

Alternatively `document` and `window` are supported as global event targets.

You can also use in any element that is added to the DOM

```
@HostListener('body:mousemove', ['$event'])
onGlobalMouseMove(event) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

Comment: Side-question, how can I get the width of the div on init?

Comment: `<div #someName>` `@ViewChild('someName') someDiv;` `ngOnInit() { console.log(this.someDiv.nativeElement.offsetWidth); }`

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34919738/getting-element-height-angular-2/34919830#34919830 (see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109956/ruler-service-not-working-as-local-dependency)

Comment: Sorry, should be `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit()`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I think it's  too general. I mean - How would you do something like this : `$("body").on('mousemove','.myClass',function(){...})` - I mean only elements who has `.myClass`

Comment: @Royi There is no support for such a thing in Angular.